# Which is better for a file sharing website: VPS or Dedicated hosting?

Tags: google, web-hosting, vps

I'm going to start a file sharing website but I can't decide what to choose : VPS or dedicated , dedicated is expensive and I'm not sure if VPS is enough for this, I know that I need Hard Disk space and Bandwidth.

Comment: Its going to depend on a host of other factors that you didn't include.   How big are the files?   How many downloads per day are you expecting?     Even with those details this question wouldn't be a good one for this website because it would be so specific that it would only be about your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make that trade off based on your business needs. A VPS is  shared with others, which means that you are sharing the server resources. The biggest risk here in my opinion lays that you can't control what other people use the server for. This can affect the performance of your application and cause unexplainable bugs that you can't trace back because you don't have full access.

In my experience these have mainly been network issues because others were filling up the uplink. A VPS is also not guaranteed to always stay at a certain place, causing downtime and dropped connections.

If you are a starting website and you can afford the risks and cons that come with sharing those resources then I don't see a problem with choosing a VPS. It is generally cheaper.

When you use a dedicated server you are the only user on the server, which just gives you more control and a slight performance gain. They are generally more expensive though. It's a trade-off really. My experience has been better with choosing smaller dedicated servers over VPS.

I would say especially with file sharing, you probably want to use your entire network capacity on your server and you don't want to negatively affect the bandwidth of other users. In this case a smaller dedicated server with a good uplink is key.

In either case, make sure to read reviews on your hosting provider.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pim i think i'll choose a dedicated paid per month ;)